# FusedLocationProviderClient returns wrong latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps, android-gps

Following the examples from [google developers site](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), I use FusedLocationProviderClient to get de last known location.

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;

// ..

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
}
```

And on button click, I call:

```
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    // Logic to handle location object
                    myposition.setText(location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
```

But, sometimes, it gives me a location that is far from current device geoposition. I've checked it on three different devices. I have declared:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

How should I use fusedlocation to get the best position with accuary? I've tried to change getlastlocation with getcurrentlocation but this last method is not available, although the docs said it is available.

Comment: Maybe user was in USA when he turned on gps for last time and then went to UK, now the `lastLocation` will return the location of USA since that was saved as last location, So if you want current location then go for it explicitly. with [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#public-tasklocation-getcurrentlocation-int-priority,-cancellationtoken-token)

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't the situation. I get this weird position in the same city.

Comment: Well read [Last location](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#public-tasklocation-getlastlocation), as it says **It is particularly well suited for applications that do not require an accurate location and that do not want to maintain extra logic for location updates.**, If you want an accurate location then read [Current Location](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#public-tasklocation-getcurrentlocation-int-priority,-cancellationtoken-token)

Comment: The last location feature does not wake the GPS or any other means to get the location, instead, it gives you a location, that was saved when the device was using GPS for the last time. **Save Charge**

Comment: My problem was that I was using play-services-location 17.0.0 and getCurrentLocation wasn't available. I have changed to 17.1 and now I can use getCurrentLocation. I have changed my code in order to use this method and I'll test it. Thanks.